# Failing to pass variables via URL to php page

Tags: php, html

Im trying to send 2 variables to my php page via a link, i can't figure out what im doing wrong. The outcome is not right. Im expecting just the display of values and instead the whole php code displays.

Thanks for helping in advance, below is my html, php and result.

My html page is named "index.html" and my php "default.php"

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
    <head>
  <title>Information sänd via adressfältet och länkar</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
  <a href="default.php?name=filip&gender=man">Link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

php:

```html
<?php

 header("Content-Type: text/plain");
 
 echo $_GET["name"];
 echo $_GET["gender"];
 
?>
```

Result:

```html
<?php

 header("Content-Type: text/plain");
 
 echo $_GET["name"];
 echo $_GET["gender"];
 
?>
```

Comment: That seems to be a problem with your server configuration not executing the php file, take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Comment: no error in above code..

Comment: where are you running this code? Is it on a hosting server, a local wamp/xamp, or directly from a local folder?

Comment: Thanks @claudio that thread solved it for me <3

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem thnx to this thread: [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

The problem was:

> Make sure you are accessing your file over your webserver using an URL like http://localhost/file.php not via local file access file://localhost/www/file.php

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of factors affecting such
first one confirm that your php module is properly configured to Apache and it reads the .php extension
two that your file is actually saved as .php if you are using a text-editor like notepad which appends the .txt file format at the end, unless you select file type as all files